# Rails 4 ActiveRecord - how to see how is interpreted a database query?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, rails-activerecord

I have these models:

**teacher**

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :days
end
```

**day**

```
class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
end
```

And running these query:

```
  active_teachers = Teacher.joins(:days).where("teacher.id" => found_teachers.pluck(:teacher_id).uniq, "days.day_name" => selected_day)
```

What the query (should) does: `found_teachers` is an array of all teachers with duplications, remove the duplicity and chose only those teachers that have classes on a respective day (`selected_day` contains a string, `Monday` for example).

Because the amount of data in the variable `active_teachers` is so big that I can't manually go record  by record (and I am not sure that I built this query properly and it does exactly what I need), I am trying to find out how is this query translated to SQL from ActiveRecord.

Usually I see everything in the terminal where is running server for the Rails app, but as of now, I don't see there this query stated.

So the question is, how can I see how the ActiveRecord query is translated to SQL?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried pasting that code into a Rails console?

Comment: try `active_teachers.to_sql`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get details from a query you're typing, you can do:

```
query.to_sql
query.explain
```

Comment: Oh perfect, didn't know this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new STDOUT
```

and run your query in rails console. So it prints out the sql queries in the console